# gcc giving garbage on c++ 11 compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I bet the solution to this question is very simple, but I'm wondering why I can't get gcc to compile my c++ 11 code.

EDIT: Code removed to simplify problem. Any program would replicate the same error.

I am using the gcc compiler 4.7 as downoaded here: https://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/detail?name=x86_64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.0-release-c%2Cc%2B%2B%2Cfortran-sjlj.zip&can=2&q=.

The command I am using to compile is simply `gcc Swamp.cpp -std=c++11`. The code only complains about c++ 11 stuff if I compile with `gcc Swamp.cpp`.

To my eyes, the errors given by the compilation is garbage:

```
 C:\Users\Owner\Documents\GitHub\CompetitiveProgramming\TestProject\CodeProject>gcc Swamp.cpp -std=c++11
 C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRKn67x.o:Swamp.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
 C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRKn67x.o:Swamp.cpp:(.text+0x30e): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
 C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRKn67x.o:Swamp.cpp:(.text+0x72e): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
 C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRKn67x.o:Swamp.cpp:(.text+0x78a): undefined reference to `std::cout'
 …etc…
```

Comment: Use g++ for c++ code

Comment: "barf" isn't a technical term.

Comment: what else do you call a ton of unrelated errors. Barf.

Comment: By the way, don't use `while (!someStream.eof())`, it will not work as you expect it to, because the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you have tried to read beyond the end of the file. Instead use e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`.

Comment: They all look pretty related to me.

Comment: Vote to close since the minimal example would be helloWorld.cpp and that too fails to compile unless you use `g++`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Joachim. I ended up changing this as well, definitely makes more sense to use while(getline(...)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different commands for compiling C++ code with GCC, `gcc` and `g++`. The difference is really only that `g++` links automatically with the C++ runtime library, and `gcc` doesn't.

The errors are all about missing symbols from the GCC C++ runtime library, and have nothing to do with C++11 features you use. To fix the errors you either need to link with the C++ runtime library yourself manually, or use the `g++` command to handle it automatically.

Comment: Yeah, dunno why I forgot/ didn't try g++. It works. Thanks!

Comment: So here's the bigger question... The code produces different output via command line than via Visual Studio. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: @BryceSandlund Step through the code with a debugger to find out.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a debugger via command line. And when I debug through Visual Studio it functions exactly how I expect it to.

Comment: @BryceSandlund You might want to add the flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` when compiling with GCC, this will enable quite a few warning options. Warnings in code is often a sign of you doing something you should not, probably something that will lead to undefined behavior. Also, when indexing the vectors, do you check that the indexing is valid?

Comment: Only getting warnings based on signed/ unsigned integer comparison with checking i < vector.size(), which shouldn't be an issue. Just changed some of the I/O which I wasn't sure about, but the outputs are still different. What do you mean by the indexing is valid?

Comment: @BryceSandlund Are all vector indexes inside the bounds of the vectors? You're never have an index out of bounds? Remember that a vectors index operator `[]` doesn't check bounds.

Comment: Problem was related to undefined behavior: `targs[s] = targs.size();`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768486/c-code-producing-different-outputs-through-visual-studio-c-and-gcc. Thanks for your help!